# App keeps state even after having process killed

Tags: react-native

We have an app in internal testing .

In this a very strange situation occurred, in almost all the cell phones if you are in a certain point of the app and kill the process, when opening the app again this starts from the beginning.

But in a cel in particular when killing the process this starts on the page where it was when it died, however this behavior occurs only in this app, in others installed on the cel it normally occurs.

I'm really out of ideas.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "appvideira",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "native-base": "2.4.1",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",
    "react-native-camera": "0.12.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-fs": "2.9.11",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.4.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "0.5.2",
    "react-native-maps": "0.20.*",
    "react-native-masked-text": "1.6.5",
    "react-native-modal": "5.4.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `code` with `package.json` file

Comment: @PritishVaidya I put the package.json, the code is very extensive, if it is some potential part, however difficult to be something in the code because it happens only in this mobile

Comment: I was just trying to check if the state is being persisted through package or not, without the code it is hard to tell what is causing the issue, you may check if the routes are being persisted through `AsyncStorage` or not.

Comment: For the routes are used https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: Yes, but for the persistance of the app's state after killing it is done through the app's storage in the device, i.e [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) on the client side. Can be done on the server side too.

Comment: But why only in this device? We have tested in more then 20 diferent devices, but only in this, one LeEco Le Max 2, it occurs

Comment: Oh !, i think i misunderstood the question, nevermind, weird device behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should really be a comment, not an answer but, being new to SO, I can't leave comments yet.

Are you aware of the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) of an application?

[image]

Comment: I know however if it was a mistake this would happen at all, but it happens only on this phone